# Spark 2.0.2 RandomForest Transform error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run Spark.ML.RandomForestClassifier

My training data was a bunch of documents which I converted to features using Tokenizer, CountVectorizer,IDF and got the final SparseVector for tf-idf features as defined below. I had a label column which was text {'Male','Female','Neutral'} which I converted to nominal variable using StringIndexer. Here is how the data looks now

Here is the code I used to create features and the corresponding ml methods.

```
class Jpsa(object):
    """ Class for ML implementation

    """



    def __init__(self,jpsa_sdf,split_perc=[0.7,0.3]):
        """ Constructor to initialze the data

        """

        # Splitting the data into training and test
        self.jpsa_train,self.jpsa_test=jpsa_sdf.randomSplit(split_perc,seed=42)
        self.jpsa_train.cache().count()
        self.jpsa_test.cache().count()



    def tf_idf(self):
        """ 
        Feature transformation using TF-IDF
        Input: 
        Param: Input Dataframe
        """

        from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
        from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, StopWordsRemover, CountVectorizer, IDF


        # Changing the labels to numeric from categorical 
        self.stringIndexer=StringIndexer(inputCol='label',outputCol='gender_label')

        # Carrying out the Tokenization of the text documents (splitting into words)
        self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="job_desc", outputCol="tokenised_text")

        # Carrying out the StopWords Removal for TF-IDF
        self.stopwordsremover=StopWordsRemover(inputCol='tokenised_text',outputCol='sw_removed_words')

        # Creating Term Frequency Vector for each word
        self.cv=CountVectorizer(inputCol="sw_removed_words", outputCol="tf_features", minDF=2.0)

        # Carrying out Inverse Document Frequency on the TF data
        self.idf=IDF(inputCol="tf_features", outputCol="output_features")

        return [self.stringIndexer,self.tokenizer,self.stopwordsremover,self.cv,self.idf]


    def rf_classifier(self):
        """ This method builds RandomForest Classifier

        """

        from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

        # Takes the "features" column and learns to predict "label"
        self.rf = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol="output_features",labelCol="gender_label")
        return [self.rf]
```

Now I instantiate this class which would split the original data into training and test using the constructor defined.

```
jpsa=Jpsa(jpsa_cleaned_sdf,[0.7,0.3])
```

Then it creates a Spark Pipeline object.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
#pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[jpsa.stringIndexer,jpsa.tokenizer,jpsa.stopwordsremover,jpsa.cv,jpsa.idf,jpsa.rf])
#pipeline = Pipeline(stages=jpsa.tfidf()+jpsa.rf_classifier())
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=jpsa.tf_idf()+jpsa.rf_classifier())
```

Now when I set up the cross validator object with hyper parameter grid space. 
This pipeline object I pass into the cross validator object for hyper parameter tuning

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
# Define a grid of hyperparameters to test:
#  - maxDepth: max depth of each decision tree in the RF ensemble
#  - maxIter: iterations, i.e., number of trees in each RF ensemble
# In this example notebook, we keep these values small.  In practice, to get the highest accuracy, you would likely want to try deeper trees (10 or higher) and more trees in the ensemble (>100).

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
  .addGrid(jpsa.rf.maxDepth, [2,4,7,10])\
 .addGrid(jpsa.rf.getNumTrees(), [100,250,500,600,700,800,900])\
 .build()

# We define an evaluation metric.  This tells CrossValidator how well we are doing by comparing
#the true labels with predictions.

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1",\
            labelCol=jpsa.rf.getLabelCol(), predictionCol=jpsa.rf.getPredictionCol())
# Declare the CrossValidator, which runs model tuning for us.
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,numFolds=5)

cvModel=cv.fit(jpsa.jpsa_train)

evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(jpsa.jpsa_train))
```

This gives an error as below:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o659.evaluate.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 136.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 136.0 (TID 131, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
```

EDIT II:

So I did further investigation and thought to go deep (isolating the parts). This time I did not use the Pipeline Object and just used Random Forest separately. Here is my code now. I am no longer using class structure.

```
def word2Vec():
    """ This function takes in the data frame of the texts and finds the Word vector 
    representation of that

    """


    from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, Word2Vec,StringIndexer


    # Carrying out the Tokenization of the text documents (splitting into words)

    # Changing the labels to numeric from categorical 
    stringIndexer=StringIndexer(inputCol='label',outputCol='label1')
    stringdf=stringIndexer.fit(df).transform(df)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="job_desc", outputCol="tokenised_text")
    tokensdf = tokenizer.transform(stringdf)

    # Implementing the word2Vec model

    word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=300, seed=42, inputCol="tokenised_text", outputCol="w2v_vector")
    w2vmodel = word2Vec.fit(tokensdf)
    w2vdf=w2vmodel.transform(tokensdf)

    return w2vdf.select('id','w2v_vector','label1')




def rf_classifier():
    """ Random Classifier 

    """

    from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
    # Takes the "features" column and learns to predict "label"
    rf =RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol="w2v_vector",labelCol="label1",maxDepth=7)
    return rf




 def split(df,split_perc):
        """ Splitting the data

        """

        jpsa_train,jpsa_test=df.randomSplit(split_perc,seed=42)
        jpsa_train.cache().count()
        jpsa_test.cache().count()

        return jpsa_train, jpsa_test



jpsa_train,jpsa_test=split(jpsa_cleaned_sdf,[0.7,0.3])

rf=rf_classifier()


from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
# Define a grid of hyperparameters to test:
#  - maxDepth: max depth of each decision tree in the GBT ensemble
#  - maxIter: iterations, i.e., number of trees in each GBT ensemble
# In this example notebook, we keep these values small.  In practice, to get the highest accuracy, you would likely want to try deeper trees (10 or higher) and more trees in the ensemble (>100).

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
  .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [2,4,7,10])\
 .addGrid(rf.numTrees, [100,250,500])\
 .build()

# We define an evaluation metric.  This tells CrossValidator how well we are doing by comparing
#the true labels with predictions.

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1",\
            labelCol=rf.getLabelCol(), predictionCol=rf.getPredictionCol())
# Declare the CrossValidator, which runs model tuning for us.
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=rf, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,numFolds=5)

cvModel=cv.fit(jpsa_train)

evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(jpsa_train)) 

0.9999999999
```

Comment: Where did the test and training data come from? Why not use `pyspark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplit`?

Comment: And back up a bit...what happens if you just do `rf_model.transform(tf_idf_test)`?

Comment: Also, `Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => vector)` makes me think that something else is going on than what we see in the snippets of code above.

Comment: @JackManey One can use either TrainValidationSplit or CrossValidation for n fold validation. That doesn't change anything. 

ii) Doesn't work and throw the same error. 

iii). Apparently I am seeing the same user defined function error with respect Spark 2.0.2 when I ran some other code (creating word2vec) vectors and it gave me the same error. The same word2vec code runs fine on 1.6. So it seems this user defined anon function error is not specific to this code only but specific to Spark 2.0.2 issue across codes.

Comment: I've used random forests in PySpark 2.0.2 recently and have had no problems. Hmmm...the hyphen in `tf-idf_features` makes it a terrible column name. Try renaming to `tf_idf_features`.

Comment: That's not an issue. I tried with various names. Spark 2.0.2 is causing this error not just for Random Forest. I ran a word2vec code on Spark 2.0.2 and it gave me the same error and the same code worked fine on 1.6

Comment: Wait....the number of features in the test and training sets are different. Why?

Comment: I am confused. This is just throwing this error for any operation on test data. It works fine if I just pass the training data to rf_model any operations. Very weird.

Comment: You have 2373 features in your training data and 716 features in your test data. Why would you expect the fitted model to work on a dataset with a different number of features?

Comment: That's correct. It won't be different no. of features. Maybe I copied the data wrong here. Wait let me cross check and put the right one

Comment: @JackManey The data I gave was a mistake. However, I ran that and it works fine since test data I gave was an issue. But my problem is originally when I run using Pipeline object and hyper parameter search. Pls check the edited question and I have changed the code and question which is giving me error

Comment: In `paramGrid`, you want to vary `jpsa.rf.numTrees`, not `jpsa.rf.getNumTrees()`

Comment: No i tried that earlier. Same issue. I changed because I checked Spark 2.0.2 docs and they said that numTrees is getting deprecated in place of this.

Comment: @JackManey The strange part is that the same code works on 1.6.1 with no error and right results. It's Spark 2.0.2 which is causing issue here with respect to Pipeline or maybe cross validator object.

Comment: No. `getNumTrees()` gets the value of the parameter. The name of the parameter is `numTrees`. And `numTrees` does not appear to be deprecated according to the docs. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier

Comment: I checked here. 

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-guide.html

Deprecations and changes of behavior
Deprecations

Deprecations in the spark.mllib and spark.ml packages include:

SPARK-14984: In spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionSummary, the model field has been deprecated.
SPARK-13784: In spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel and spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel, the numTrees parameter has been deprecated in favor of getNumTrees method.

Also I have used numTress too. Doesn't work

Comment: Ah, so it has. Well, there's your problem. The `getNumTrees` method returns an integer, not a parameter. Thus, it can't be used as a parameter in a grid search.

Comment: Well, I am even using numTrees. Even that doesn't help

Comment: Right...because it's deprecated.....

Comment: @JackManey No It's not a numTrees issue. I went further down and tried to isolate the code. Now I just used random forest and no pipelining. So basically creating new data frame for each transformation (Tokenizer, StringIndexer etc) and then in cross validator pass estimator as rf (random forest object) instead of Pipeline object earlier. It runs fine and gives the output. But the moment i put it as part of Pipeline like the first edit , it breaks down and throws the same error. Check Edit II